# Fill empty cells between two filled cells

Tags: vba, excel, cells

The Situation:
On the Cell "A1" I have the value "1"
On the Cell "A10" I have the value "2"
On the Cell "A20" I have the value "3"
On the Cell "A30" I have the value "4"

What I want to do with Excel VBA:
Between A1 and A10 there are empty cells. I want that A2:A9 is filled with the value of A10, that means "2".
Between A10 and A20 there are empty cells. I want that A11:19 is filled with the value of A20, that means "3".

The problem is, the range A1 to A30 is not fixed. I want to search the whole row for cells which are not empty and to fill the cells between them with the upper cell which is filled.

EDIT:
To explain more, I have an Access Database with a table which is filled with Dates and a table which is filled with numbers.

I want to make a Report to an Excel Sheet.

```vb
Dim Daten As Variant
Daten = Array(rs!DatumJMinus8Monate, rs!DatumJ, rs!DatumI, rs!DatumH, rs!DatumG, rs!DatumF, rs!DatumE, rs!DatumD, rs!DatumC, rs!DatumB, rs!DatumA, rs!DatumA4Monate)
Dim Bedarfe As Variant
Bedarfe = Array(rs!BedarfJ8Monate, rs!BedarfJ, rs!BedarfI, rs!BedarfH, rs!BedarfG, rs!BedarfF, rs!Bedarfe, rs!BedarfD, rs!BedarfC, rs!BedarfB, rs!BedarfA, rs!BedarfA, "")

Dim neuereintrag As Boolean
bedarfindex = 0
For Each element In Daten
    i = 7
    For jahre = 1 To 10
        If Cells(1, i + 1) = Year(element) Then
            For monate = 1 To 12
                If Cells(2, i + monate) = Month(element) Then
                    Cells(zeile, i + monate) = Bedarfe(bedarfindex)
                    Cells(zeile, i + monate).Font.Bold = True
                    bedarfindex = bedarfindex + 1
                    neuereintrag = True
                ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(zeile, i + monate)) Or neuereintrag = True Then
                    Cells(zeile, i + monate) = Bedarfe(bedarfindex)
                    neuereintrag = False
                End If
            Next monate
        End If
        i = i + 12
    Next jahre
Next element
```

In the picture the numbers in the red circles have to be deleted.

[image: Excel-Report-Sheet Screenshot]

Comment: You have said that you have tried many ways, can you show some of what you did? This is not a 'Code for Me' site, but we will help you reach your goal if you give us something to start with!

Comment: Edit your question and add your `code` in there.

Comment: I will do that in a few minutes, Need some time

Comment: the code is in german, do you want me to Change the variable names to english?

Comment: `On the Cell "A30" i have the value "4"` - does this value get copied down to row 1048576 / 65536?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook
Oh sorry, i realized just now that i made a mistake. It shouldn't be A1, A10, A20, A30, what I've meant was A1,H1,O1, V1 and so on, I'm really sorry for that mistake in the question

Answer (score 0):

On way to work from the bottom upwards:

```
Sub FillUp()
    Dim N As Long
    Dim i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, that works really nice! Thank you!
The only Thing is, i made a mistake on the description. 
I wanted to fill the cells between A1,H1,O1 and so on. 
Not a column, but a row.
I will try to Change your code but i would also be thankful for you if you could say me what i have to Change that it will works also with rows?

Comment: Thank you man! I did it! You are my heroo!

This is the code:
`Sub FillUp()
    Dim N As Long
    Dim i As Long
    N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = N - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "" Then Cells(1, i).Value = Cells(1, i + 1).Value
    Next i
End Sub`

Comment: @oemerkk  Good Job !!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.  It needs a bit of work as it will fail if two values are next to each other, or column 1 doesn't contain a value.

```
Sub AutoFill()

    Dim rCell1 As Range, rCell2 As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find the last column containing data, set both references to this
        'so the Do While doesn't fall over on the first loop.
        Set rCell2 = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft) '1 is the row number it's looking at.
        Set rCell1 = rCell2

        'Find next cell to the left containing data and fill between these two columns.
        Do While rCell1.Column <> 1
            Set rCell1 = rCell2.End(xlToLeft)
            .Range(rCell1, rCell2.Offset(, -1)).FillRight
            Set rCell2 = rCell1
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```